# What would trip a Eaton 20a gfci breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci

Fairly new less than one month old Eaton 20a gfci breaker to trip with nothing but the white common coil attached. Meaning the breaker is in the main box with no load circuit connected. Meaning I pulled the wires off and pushed to the side.

Back story called out on a service call pool motor down. The original breaker would not reset with or without the load remove hots pushed aside it wouldn’t reset so installed new Eaton breaker checked for motor operation, dead short bad motor. Installed new motor powered up fired up all is well.

Two weeks later return call motor down. I go out try the tripped breaker immediately trips check wiring at motor all is well no shorts, remove hots from new breaker try to reset  breaker no load nothing but coiled common attached no go..... it immediately trips.

I’m stumped defective breaker?

Comment: Where did you buy the breaker?

Comment: Is this a CH (tan handle, skinny) or a BR (black handle, fat)? Also, I take it you removed *both* the load-hot *and* the load-neutral from the suspect breaker when disconnecting the circuit from it, or did you just disconnect the load-hot?

Comment: Yeah if you left load neutral attached, that would not work as a GFCI test.

Comment: It’s 240v 2 pole disconnected those hots but left the coiled white from the breaker attached to the panels neutral bar so it was just a installed breaker with no outgoing wiring attached just the breaker inserted with the included white cooled wire attached

Comment: And it’s the fat 2pole black got it at Home Depot I guess I removed both load hots essentially here’s what I got a breaker I. The panel with nothing connected except the coiled white wire that is attached when you get the breaker. It is attached to the neutral bar in the box same location the one I removed was. Nothing is attached to the 2 pole hots nor the neutral coiled wire. No wiring no load you goto reset it trips immediately like the test button is stuck it’s doing exactly what the pulled one did, been working fine for 3weeks

Comment: New breaker new motor :)